# Importing a Jar file into an nsf with Build Automatically switch on causes a recurring build

Tags: build, jar, xpages

Using DDE if I import a Jar file into an nsf, either using the new Jar Design element or via web-inf\lib, then as soon as I save an xpage the workspace goes into constant rebuild.  It rebuilds the workspaces, stops, rebuilds, stops etc.

It will only stop for good if I delete the jar design element, remove it from the build path or turn Build Automatically off.

I've tried this with a selection of different Jars on a local database with no network connection and on a server copy, all result in the same constant rebuild.

Referencing an external jar works fine but I'd prefer to keep it in the nsf.

Am using DDE 9.0

I'm guessing it's somehow related to this issue which describes how jars in nsfs have to be detached to compile. It's as if this detachment causes an update which makes DDE think it has to rebuild again
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xpages+jar+build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works for me:

- switch off automatic build
- import Jar
- add Jar to build path
- link NSF to onDisk project
- Set DDE to monitor changes automatically (in preferences)
- switch back on automatic build

Then when you need to replace the Jar with a newer version, just copy it into the OnDisk project - you need to restart the http preview after replacing the jar.

Comment: NB: I had to 
*switch off automatic build
*copy jar into the web-inf/lib dir in the On Disk Project
*link NSF to onDisk Project
*add jar to build path